# Designing a single-ended to differential driver to DC2588A-A evaluation board

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, driver, differential, differential-amplifier

I'd like to test the DC2588A-A, and I noticed that the [user guide](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC2588AF.PDF) mentions it's driven by a pair of ADA4899-1 DRIVER amplifiers. However, the user guide doesn't provide clear information about the purpose of these amplifiers. Additionally, it mentions that they need to be driven differentially, but I'm unsure about how to do that.

[image: Pair of ADA4899-1 driver amplifiers]

What do I need to consider if I have to design a single-ended to differential driver circuit when the evaluation board already has internal driver amplifiers.

Comment: Hello! Can you please add a link to the datasheet you refer to? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC2588AF.PDF

Comment: Thanks, and could you edit it into your question? There's a link button where it can be done.

Comment: @MiNiMe I agree with the request, though I have already added the link to the question. (PS, Abdel, that's a user guide, not a data sheet)

Comment: Ok I noticed the user guide link but it wasn't the datasheet in question.

Comment: @MiNiMe thing is a minimal demo board, to the best of my knowledge, no datasheet exists, only the guide and the schematics.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Correct, noticed that too.

Answer (score 2):

It's an ADC, which samples the input. For that, the input must be able to drive a capacitive load – the sample-and-hold input of the ADC. You should really read the datasheet of the ADC, it explains and illustrates that quite nicely:

[image: Equivalent circuit for the differential analog inputs of the LTC2387-16, showing permanently connected 2 pF and switched 18 pF]

You don't want that capacitive load to affect the source of the signal, which might have a significantly higher impedance. Also, you don't want the switching noise of switching from "hold" to "sample" mode (p. 2 of the datasheet, C<sub>IN</sub>) to feed upwards into the thing you want to observe.

The need for the source to have low impedance is true for basically any ADC, but in some cases your source impedance is low enough and you can do without.

What is true for truly all ADCs is that there's need for *anti-aliasing filtering* (if that word is new, brush up your basic knowledge on ADCs on wikipedia, please!). And if you look at the schematic, R50 together with C75 (and R49 together with C73) form low-pass filters. But to make these actually work as reliable, low-distortion low-pass filters, you need to make both true:

1. The resistance of the source, including the R, needs to be much lower than the resistance of what is connected to the filter's "output"
2. The capacity of the C needs to be much larger than the capacity of what is connected to the filter's "output"

to effectively act as *unloaded* complex voltage divider (remember how you learned about why an RC works, probably in a first semester lecture!).

Now, to make that work, the source needs to be able to drive this relatively strong RC – so you practically everywhere that you can find an ADC find a buffer feeding an anti-aliasing filter. (Or rather, you typically even find an active filter containing opamps itself; but that route was not chosen here.)

**EDIT**: Um, seriously, the [LTC2387-16 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/238716f.pdf) actually contains a full paragraph that explains this on page 13. So, maybe the takeaway here is that you can save yourself and other people quite some time if you read the datasheets of the things you use!

> **Input Drive Circuits**
>
> A low impedance source can directly drive the high impedance inputs of the LTC2387-16 without gain error. A high impedance source should be buffered to minimize settling time during acquisition and to optimize the distortion performance of the ADC. Minimizing settling time is important even for DC signals because the ADC inputs draw a current spike when entering acquisition.
>
> For best performance, a buffer amplifier should be used to drive the analog inputs of the LTC2387-16. The amplifier provides low output impedance enabling fast settling of the analog signal during the acquisition phase. It also provides isolation between the signal source and the current spike drawn by the ADC inputs when entering acquisition.
>
> […]
>
> **Input Currents**
>
> One of the biggest challenges in coupling an amplifier to the LTC2387-16 is in dealing with current spikes drawn by analog inputs at the start of each acquisition phase.
>
> The analog inputs may be modeled as a switched capacitor load on the drive circuit. A drive circuit may rely partially on attenuating switched-capacitor current spikes with small filter capacitors placed directly at the ADC inputs and partially on the driver amplifier having sufficient bandwidth to recover from the residual disturbance. Amplifiers optimized for DC performance may not have sufficient bandwidth to fully recover at the ADC’s maximum conversion rate, which can produce nonlinearity and other errors. Coupling filter circuits may be classified in two broad categories:
>
> […]

---

> Additionally, it mentions that they need to be driven differentially, but I'm unsure about how to do that.

Not at all. Your ADC can be set to single-ended conversion mode, and as long as you tie the other input to something constant (e.g., the common mode reference voltage) you're fine. Sure, you can't reach maximum SFDR, but is that something you care about at this stage of design? Probably not. Of course, if you need to do any signal preconditioning on your analog signal, anyway, for example because its amplitude is nowhere near 8.192 Vpp differential (4.096 Vpp single-ended), then you do that with differential amplifiers. As mentioned in the same user guide, there's demo boards from the same company for that, which you are absolutely free to copy and modify.

Note that having less maximum amplitude costs you effective number of bits. But since this is a pretty nice ADC, you get nearly 16 bit of ENOB anyways, so you're in wide swaths limited by the noise of your source; adding an amplifier that doubles your signal's amplitude (for example, by converting a single-ended Vpp=4 V signal into a differential Vpp=8 V signal), but decreases the SNR by more than 6 dB is simply making your output worse, not better. (Signal processing specifics do apply; if you're sampling a large dynamic range in heavy oversampling and rely on natural dithering to give you information about very weak signals, this might look different, because you would *need* some noise in the 2 to 3 least significant bits, but: different story. You are the one that chose this ADC, so you must be the one with an idea of what you want to do with the digitized signal afterwards.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and feedback, i appreciate it